# Transform/scale multiple images onto the same position in GIMP

Tags: gimp, scale

Just started to learn GIMP today. Here's my question.

**I have**

- an image of a 3d-object in a certain perspective
- multiple images (all the same size) certain data
- GIMP

**I'd like to**

- transform/scale the rectangular data images to a certain face of the picture of the 3d-body
- repeat the process for all image without the need to transform/scale the subsequent images again

I have been able to transform/scale a single image into the desired place on the 3d-body, but unfortunately I am not able to put the following images into the exact same place. My idea is to create some kind of transformed/scaled empty layer and paste every image into it.

**The question**

Is there a way to do the aforementioned?

**Thanks in advance!**

A quick sketch of the problem (blue rectangular image, transform vertices to vertices' on A, do it multiple times):

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For batch use you can use a shell script built around ImageMagick that has a [perspective transform](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective).

With Gimp, if the images are not too big (or you have RAM to spare) you can:

- Open the base image in Gimp
- Use `File>Open as layers` to load all images to transform in the same Gimp image (the file selector for this allows you to select several files)
- [Chain-link the layers in the Layers list](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-attributes) (you can mass-link/unlink items by shift-clicking one of them)
- Apply the [Perspective transform](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-perspective.html) to one of them
- When you "commit" the transform, it is applied to all other "chained" layers
- Export the images (for instance using the [`ofn-export-layers`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) script)

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift and qualified answer! I decided to pick the GUI-way instead of using a shell script. I have been able to transform and export every image. Thanks again.

Comment: One more question: is there a way to apply the base image as background to all the transformed layers? At the moment all the transformed layers have a transparent background instead.

Comment: See the [`interleave-layers`](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/animationtools.shtml) script.  Once you have adjusted the perspective on all layers, use it in Sprite mode. Hide your background layer, and give it to the script to merge under all others. Once th emerge is done, export the layers.

Comment: Thanks again, everything is just fine now!